# TestNG 6.4 with ant creatin TestNG 6.3 Reports?

Tags: java, ant, testng

I upgraded to TestNG 6.4. Now when I execute a Test-Suite from within Eclipse(with TestNG plugin) the test got "the new look". But if I execute the same Test-Suite with ant the reports look the same as with TestNG 6.3. Why is that? How can I get ant to create the reports with the new look?

**EDIT:**

I found a solution... I have to add the testng-6.4.jar before the selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar to the class path if you do it the other way around you get the old reports. Since the selenium.jar contains testng in an older version...

New Reports:

```
<path id="classpath">
  <pathelement location="bin"/>
  <pathelement location="lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="lib/testng-6.4.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="testsuites"/>
</path>
```

Old Reports:

```
<path id="classpath">
  <pathelement location="bin"/>
  <pathelement location="lib/testng-6.4.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="testsuites"/>
</path>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your ant build is using the 6.4 jar file?

Comment: I cannot say for sure. I ve no entry in ant that shows which jar it is using. I added the testNG as Libary with eclipse. I don't have a 6.3 jar lying around. Could it be using the TestNG that Selenium has hidden somewhere inside?

Comment: I added the 6.4jar. I still keeps creating old reportrs.

Comment: How did you add it? How are you running TestNG? The best way to make sure you're doing the right thing in situations like these is to run from the command line (no ant, not Maven, no IDE).

Comment: I'll post my ant build.xml on monday when I am back at work ;-) I am running my ant through a suite or a suite that contains multiple other suites.

Comment: I meant I am running my tests through a suite or a suite that contains other suites. The last one gets executed through ant.